# ASP.Net Web Application Choose Client Side Directory

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the requirement to allow a user to provide a local directory path via a UI in a web application so that we can save it to our database. Our other program (a winforms app) will then use this path to store files (actually recordings) that they have created via the app.

Ideally I would like to remove as much room for human error as possible i.e. only let them use paths that exist so would prefer to have some kind of select directory dialog that forces them to use existing directories however I have read that this is not possible on client side code for security reasons which of course makes total sense but is there some way that this can be achieved? So far I have been unable to find anything of use besides just letting them type it in and I am not happy with the lack of control over the path they enter.

Comment: How about asking to upload a file from that folder  and grab the path? Bit stupid I know .. Easier than typing for the user.

Comment: Hmm I see what you are saying. It would require a file to be present however I would have thought? If they are setting up for the first time said file woulndt be available and it is a little clumsy to have to get them to create a file for each path they want to change to. It may an idea to work with for now though. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes, more choices simply don't make things easier for your Customer.

The "standard" for Windows App's is storing things in the user's Documents directory, and then possibly an App specific folder within the user's Documents directory.

I would just go with the default expectation, the User's Documents directory.

When you are thinking about this, ask yourself what the code should do if the directory the user selected disappears, for whatever reason. This could happen because the user changes computers between when they setup this thing using your WebUI and when they user the WinForm's client.

Going with the standard behavior, Documents folder and perhaps then a subdirectory named after the App, obviates all of these problems.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks John. I like your thinking. I think I would have to allow them to provide a server address or similar too also in case they actually want to store the files on a different machine. Its a tricky one as the win forms app code already exists but is written in Delphi and I havent a clue when it comes to Delphi. Usually however there is one path per company rather one per user. The user in question would be dealing with the administration for the individual company entries if that makes sense. I believe that each user in the company group would then save to the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can have them choose a file on their computer and use that path.

For this you can use the [FileControl](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/controls/file-upload-control/)